# Rendering VDB Smoke in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, import, workflow, smoke-simulation

I need to export some files from Houdini into Blender to render in Cycles. That being said, I can either export them as [bgeo], [vdb], or [sim] files. I can't seem to find out if Blender can handle any of those file types though; or how to render one for that reason. Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133107/import-openvdb-files/133113#133113

Comment: Yes I read that post. It doesn't tell you how to import them though, thats the issue.