# How to write custom volume attributes using python?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I was wondering how I could write a custom attribute just like *density* and *flame* using python. My intention is to use it for volume rendering so if there's a strict data structure I have to follow it's okay.

Comment: Have a look into [OpenVDB](https://www.openvdb.org/) although I'm not sure whether you can calculate the vbds using python, takes ages probably. Related: [Import OpenVDB files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133113/3710)

Comment: Okay do you know at least where the density girds are stored?